# How to send email using angular js and ionic framework

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, email, ionic-framework

I tried sending **email** by referring various links but in vain.I just want to send email and below is my code for sending email. Please suggest the changes .
Thanks in advance :)
**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="starter" ng-controller="ExampleController">

    <ion-pane>
      <ion-content>
        <div class="padding">
        <button  class="button button-icon icon ion-email" ng-click="vesitEmail()">
          Send Email
        </button>
        </div>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-pane>
  </body>
</html>
```

App.js

```
var example=angular.module('starter', ['ionic','ngCordova'])
.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
        cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
        cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
});
example.controller('ExampleController', function($scope,$cordovaEmailComposer) {
  $cordovaEmailComposer.isAvailable().then(function() {
    // is available
    alert("available");
  }, function () {
    // not available
    alert("not available");
  });
  $scope.vesitEmail = function(){
    var email = {
      to: 'siddhesh.kalgaonkar@ves.ac.in',
      cc: 'monish.gupte@mservices.in',
      bcc: null,
      attachments: null,
      subject: 'Mail subject',
      body: 'How are you? Nice greetings from Leipzig',
      isHtml: true
    };

    $cordovaEmailComposer.open(email).then(null, function () {
      // user cancelled email
    });
  }
  window.alert("Message Sent");
});
```

When i test in browser it shows below error :

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'plugins' of undefined
```

and when i test it on mobile phone it doesnt work on it as well.

Comment: Can you confirm window.cordova and window.cordova.plugins are available?

Comment: just in case..!check 'org.apache.cordova.statusbar' plugin is installed..!as u are using 'window.StatusBar'..!

Comment: plugins problem is solved sir . email poblem not solved yet :(

Answer (score 0):

For email, you will have to install ***[Cordova Email Plugin](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-email-composer)***. The plugin provides access to the standard interface that manages the editing and sending an email message. Install using **[CLI](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/cli/index.html)**

***cordova plugin add https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-email-composer.git***

```
$scope.vesitEmail = function(){
    cordova.plugins.email.isAvailable(
      function (isAvailable) {
        if(isAvailable){
          cordova.plugins.email.open({
            to:      [''],
            cc:      [''],
            bcc:     [''],
            subject: '',
            body:    ''
          });     
        }else{
          alert('Service is not available.');
        }
      }
    );
};
```

Comment: i tested your code on mobile @Ved sir but doesnt work :(

Comment: On browser on button click it gives TypeError: Cannot read property 'plugins' of undefined
    at Scope.$scope.vesitEmail

Comment: are you installed plugin propperly..? Don't check in browser, test in phonegap build app.

Comment: yes i have installed "cordova plugin add https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-email-composer.git" by writing it in cmd and project's folder but still of no use :(

Comment: try to put your code inside $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {..}).

Comment: But i want it on button click sir not on page loading :(

Comment: first put $ionicPlatform.ready(function()} in your controller then put your  button click function inside it...OR check are you added "cordova_plugins.js" file in your index.html..?

Comment: Add "cordova_plugins.js" file in your index.html

Comment: it is not plugin error . thanks alot sir for trying to help me .if you still know any other options please let me know :)

Answer (score 0):

I have used like this after installing [Cordova Email Plugin](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-email-composer) in my project.. hope it may help...

```
$scope.sendEmail = function () {
          if (window.plugins && window.plugins.emailComposer) {
            window.plugins.emailComposer.showEmailComposerWithCallback(function (result) {
              alert(result);
            },
              "Feedback Form", // Subject
              $scope.emailText[0].body,                      // Body
              ["ameerhamza810@gmail.com"],    // To
              null,                    // CC
              null,                    // BCC
              false,                   // isHTML
              null,                    // Attachments
              null);                   // Attachment Data
          }
        }
```

Comment: Doesnt work . Tested on mobile as well . Doesnt give any error

Comment: have you installed plugin correctly?
define any body text in place of $scope.emailText[0].body

Comment: Yeah i have installed plugins correctly still Not working sir :(